# Unhandled promise rejection warning returning null

Tags: javascript, node.js

I appear to have an unhandled promise rejection that I cannot find...

I've run nodejs with `--trace-warnings`, and I have the following code at the top of my script:

```
process.on('unhandledRejection', (reason, p) => {
  console.log('Unhandled Rejection at:', p, 'reason:', reason);
  console.log(p)
  console.log(reason)
});
```

When the promise is rejected, I see:

```
Unhandled Rejection at: Promise { <rejected> null } reason: null
Promise { <rejected> null }
null
```

I've checked the few async functions and promises I have, and they all have `.catch()`'s... What the heck is going on here? How can I find out where the rejection is coming from?

Some code. I have the following async function in my class:

```
async loop() {
    console.log("starting loop")
    if ( this.state != this.STOPPED ) {
        switch (this.case) {
            case this.POLLING:
                console.log("Start polling")
                await Promise.all(this.symbols.map(symbol => {
                    return this.fetch(symbol)
                })).then(() => {
                    ...
                }).catch(error => {
                    ...
                })
                for (let symbol of this.symbols) {
                    await this.process(symbol).then(() => {
                        ...                         
                    }).catch(error => {
                        ...
                    })
                } //for
                for (let openPosition of this.openPositions) {
                    this.log.push(openPosition.toLogString())
                }
                console.log("end polling")
                break
        } //state selection case
        console.log(this.log.formatTimestamp(Date.now()))
        this.log.dump()
        this.log.clear()
        console.log("done dumping")
        setTimeout(this.loop.bind(this), 0)
    }
}
```

The weird thing is the output, which repeats:

```
starting loop
Start polling
end polling
done dumping
Unhandled Rejection at: Promise { <rejected> null } reason: null
Promise { <rejected> null }
null
```

The warning shows up basically on the 
`setTimeout()` call. Not sure why that's an issue. Also worth noting is that I seem to get a different number of promise rejections depending on how many elements there are in the array `this.OpenPositions`. I get n-1 errors for n>1, where n is the number of elements.

Comment: you might have written a promise where you might not have handled the error response correctly. Can you please add some code?

Comment: Can you elaborate? I can't just post every async function or promise, but if there's something specific I can post chunks.

Comment: There must be a line number some where in error in console or terminal indicating

Comment: Well, you need to narrow down which promise has an unhandled rejection.  I would hope you can figure out which promises are involved in the operation when you get this error showing and narrow it down to those.  You could also temporarily or permanently switch to the [Bluebird promise library](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/getting-started.html) which is much more likely to give you a stack trace for an unhandled rejection.

Comment: There is no line number anywhere, hence my problem. If I get rid of the `process.on()`, it'll give me a similar message with no line number. nodejs usually gives me a trace for unhandled promise rejections, so I'm not sure what's going on here.

The case statement that's executing when this warning pops up has a `Promise.all()`, which has a `.catch()`, and an `await function()` which also has one.

Comment: @Sravan added some code... this is an odd problem

Answer (score 0):

I don't know that this is the problem, but it seems like one of few possibilities.

An `async` function returns a promise, which means your `loop()` function returns a promise. If there is an error inside this function that is not part of a different promise, those errors will turn into unhandled rejections. Consider:

```js
let obj = {
    count: 0,
    async loop() {
      this.count++
        console.log("running: ", this.count)
      if (this.count == 2) throw ("whoops")
      if (this.count < 2) {
        setTimeout(this.loop.bind(this), 0)
    } 
  }
}
obj.loop()
```

The `throw()` will result in an unhandled promise rejection even though there are no promises in the function.  (I think the snippet swallows them, but you can see it in the console)

To catch these you need a `catch` on `loop()` itself. This might be a little less convenient with the way you are calling it in the timeout, but you could do something like:

```js
let obj = {
  count: 0,
  async loop() {
    this.count++
      console.log("running: ", this.count)
    if (this.count == 2) throw ("whoops")
    if (this.count < 2) {
      if (this.count < 2) {
        setTimeout(() => this.loop()
        .catch(err => console.log("caught error: ", err)), 0)
      }
    }
    return this.count
  }

}
obj.loop().catch(err => console.log("caught error outside: ", err))
```

Comment: `(function() { ... }).bind(this)` can be simplified to `() => { ... }`

Comment: I suspect you're right! Thanks! Let's see what happens

Comment: @Mark_M re: the way I'm calling the loop... it seemed like the most "javascript-y" way to do it. Is there a better way? I thought I couldn't use a while loop because the script also runs a nodejs webserver in the background so it can't block